# ANSIBLE: boto - "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ansible, boto

Using **ansible=2.10.0** and **boto=2.49.0**, When trying to execute ec2_vol playbook for manage disk to AWS instance with Proxy environment.
Getting this error -

> connection.py",line 796, in proxy_ssl, sock.sendall("CONNECT %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % host), TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str',

There is open PR to boto to fix it, But not merged yet - https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3699.
There is community module is also not available for ec2_vol like -  https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/aws.

Is there any solution other than using fork to resolve it like monkeypatching in python?

Comment: You have influence over the python interpreter used for those `ec2_vol` tasks, so you can work around it by using python2 for that one task, or (as you mentioned) you can apply the patch to the boto library as part of your playbook (via `lineinfile:` or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long R&D, I have found the solution of above error -

We can use the `amazon.aws:1.4.1` version to resolve the issue.
I was not throwing an error as above of the ec2_vol task.